# Manipulating and Converting PixelData of CT Image with fo-dicom in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, dicom, fo-dicom

For some tests I'm trying to manipulate the `PixelData` element of a CT image stored in dicom format and write it back in the file with *Fellow Oak Dicom* in C#. After some research I found out that the matrix I want to deal with is in the `Buffer` of `PixelData` stored in a `byte`-array. So I wrote following code:

```
DicomFile ctFile = DicomFile.Open(image);
var pixDat = ctFile.Dataset.Get<byte[]>(DicomTag.PixelData);

for (int i = 0; i < pixData.Length; i++)
{
    pixDat[i] = Convert.ToByte(200);
}

ctFile.Dataset.AddOrUpdate<byte[]>(DicomTag.PixelData, pixDat);
ctFile.Save("new file folder");
```

This was my first try and I got an `Exception` at the `AddOrUpdate` command because it was unable to convert a `byte`-array to OB.
Reading e.g. Pianykh's book about DICOM, OB means *Other Byte String*. But up to now I'm unable to convert the manipulated `byte`-array to OB. When I tried this code snippet:

```
DicomOtherByte dob = new DicomOtherByte(DicomTag.PixelData, pixDat);
ctFile.Dataset.AddOrUpdate<DicomOtherByte>(DicomTag.PixelData, dob);
```

the `Exception` still is calling at `AddOrUpdate` for being unable to convert the item to OB. Searching here at stackoverflow, fo-dicom documentation in git or with google I still didn't get a clue how to deal with it. So I'm wondering how to convert my manipulated matrix to OB, because I thought `DicomOtherByte` is OB.

EDIT: The `Exception` is "Unable to create DICOM element of type OB with values of type Dicom.DicomOtherByte" - System.InvalidOperationException

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited and added the short description VS shows me for the exception. And I changed the `foreach` loop to a `for` loop. You were right. Looked a bit strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pixel data in a Dicom Dataset is something very special. It cannot easily be read or written as a single Tag. Fo-Dicom has special functions and classes to work with pixel data.

Here is an example:

```
DicomFile ctFile = DicomFile.Open(@"C:\Temp\original.dcm");

// Create PixelData object to represent pixel data in dataset
DicomPixelData pixelData = DicomPixelData.Create(ctFile.Dataset);
// Get Raw Data
byte[] originalRawBytes = pixelData.GetFrame(0).Data;

// Create new array with modified data
byte[] modifiedRawBytes = new byte[originalRawBytes.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < originalRawBytes.Length; i++)
{
    modifiedRawBytes[i] = (byte)(originalRawBytes[i] + 100);
}

// Create new buffer supporting IByteBuffer to contain the modified data
MemoryByteBuffer modified = new MemoryByteBuffer(modifiedRawBytes);

// Write back modified pixel data
ctFile.Dataset.AddOrUpdatePixelData(DicomVR.OB, modified);

ctFile.Save(@"C:\Temp\Modified.dcm");
```

Note that there more helper classes to work with pixel data directly in a specific format like `PixelDataConverter` and `PixelDataFactory`.

Also, if you want to work with actual images, use the `DicomImage` class.

```
DicomImage image = new DicomImage(ctFile.Dataset);
```

Comment: That solution is very good, thank you. But I have another question about PixelData. Are there different kinds of PixelData in different files? Seemed to me like PixelData of CT Images are different to e.g. RTDOSE PixelData.

Comment: Have a look at https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/rt-dose/image-pixel . These attributes will tell you what pixel data you have