# How to replace the Pixel Data of DICOM file using fo-DICOM?

Tags: c#, dicom, fo-dicom

I want to replace the pixel data of a DICOM file with another one. I used this code:

```
public bool ImportImage(string imageFile, string newFilePah, string oldDicomFile)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFile);
        bitmap = GetValidImage(bitmap);
        int rows, columns;
        byte[] pixels = GetPixels(bitmap, out rows, out columns);
        MemoryByteBuffer buffer = new MemoryByteBuffer(pixels);
        DicomDataset dataset = new DicomDataset();
        var df = DicomFile.Open(oldDicomFile);
        FillDataset(ref dataset, df);

        DicomTransferSyntax dicomTransfer = df.Dataset.Get<DicomTransferSyntax>(DicomTag.TransferSyntaxUID, DicomTransferSyntax.JPEGProcess14);
        dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.PhotometricInterpretation, PhotometricInterpretation.Rgb.Value);
        dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.Rows, (ushort)rows);
        dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.Columns, (ushort)columns);
        dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.BitsAllocated, (ushort)8);
        DicomPixelData pixelData = DicomPixelData.Create(dataset, true);
        pixelData.BitsStored = 8;
        pixelData.SamplesPerPixel = 3;
        pixelData.HighBit = 7;
        pixelData.PixelRepresentation = 0;
        pixelData.PlanarConfiguration = 0;
        pixelData.AddFrame(buffer);

        DicomFile dicomfile = new DicomFile(dataset.Clone(dicomTransfer));
        dicomfile.Save(newFilePah);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ddd) { return false; }
}
private void FillDataset(ref DicomDataset dataset, DicomFile df)
{
    foreach(var item in df.Dataset)
    {
        if(!item.Tag.Group.ToString().Equals("7FE0") && !item.Tag.Group.ToString().Equals("40"))
            dataset.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The output DICOM file loses many tags which affect image display.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297176/5779732) answer. But the `AddOrUpdatePixelData` method used in that answer is deprecated in version v4.0.0-rc1 that I am using. So that answer does not help me.

Is there any other way to change the pixel data of a DICOM file using fo-DICOM?

Comment: when updating to fo-dicom 4.0.2 I also ran into the AddOrUpdatePixelData method being obsolete issue.  By following the message in the obsolete tag,  I replaced the method call with:  var pixelData= DicomPixelData.Create(dataset, true);  //2nd parameter is true since we are adding new data here
                    pixelData.AddFrame(buffer);

Answer (score 5):

Following code does replace the pixel data correctly.

```
public static bool ImportImage(string imageFile, string newFilePah, string oldDicomFile)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFile);
    int rows, columns;
    byte[] pixels = GetPixels(bitmap, out rows, out columns);
    MemoryByteBuffer buffer = new MemoryByteBuffer(pixels);
    DicomDataset dataset = new DicomDataset();
    var dicomfile = DicomFile.Open(oldDicomFile);
    dataset = dicomfile.Dataset.Clone();

    dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.PhotometricInterpretation, PhotometricInterpretation.Rgb.Value);
    dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.Rows, (ushort)rows);
    dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.Columns, (ushort)columns);
    dataset.AddOrUpdate(DicomTag.BitsAllocated, (ushort)8);

    DicomPixelData pixelData = DicomPixelData.Create(dataset, true);
    pixelData.BitsStored = 8;
    pixelData.SamplesPerPixel = 3;
    pixelData.HighBit = 7;
    pixelData.PhotometricInterpretation = PhotometricInterpretation.Rgb;
    pixelData.PixelRepresentation = 0;
    pixelData.PlanarConfiguration = 0;
    pixelData.Height = (ushort)rows;
    pixelData.Width = (ushort)columns;
    pixelData.AddFrame(buffer);

    dicomfile = new DicomFile(dataset);
    dicomfile.Save(newFilePah);
    return true;
}

private static byte[] GetPixels(Bitmap bitmap, out int rows, out int columns)
{
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        rows = bitmap.Height;
        columns = bitmap.Width;
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can see I have cleaned up your code much.

But the major change is using `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp` instead of other formats. This depends on actual input image format. Use the format as that of input image.

For detailed insight, please refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/mdubey82/4030263) source code on github.